# Corosync caused a 100% CPU load after a node disappeared. How to fix it?

Tags: cluster, high-availability, pacemaker, corosync

A general setup (the very first for me) of Corosync + Pacemaker is made upon 4 Virtual Servers with a VirtualIP, a private network is organised with a help of OpenVPN.

```
corosync-2.4.3-4.el7.x86_64
corosynclib-2.4.3-4.el7.x86_64
pacemaker-1.1.19-8.el7_6.4.x86_64
pacemaker-cli-1.1.19-8.el7_6.4.x86_64
pacemaker-cluster-libs-1.1.19-8.el7_6.4.x86_64
pacemaker-libs-1.1.19-8.el7_6.4.x86_64
pcs-0.9.165-6.el7.centos.1.x86_64
```

So I have here 4 VPS with CentOS 7, running OpenVPN. The cluster status in a regular state:

```
# pcs status
Cluster name: hacluster
Stack: corosync
Current DC: node2 (version 1.1.19-8.el7_6.4-c3c624ea3d) - partition with quorum
Last updated: Sat Jun 15 14:00:36 2019
Last change: Sat Jun 15 02:25:39 2019 by hacluster via crmd on platinum

4 nodes configured
1 resource configured

Online: [ node1 node2 node3 master ]

Full list of resources:

 virtualIP      (ocf::heartbeat:IPaddr2):       Started node1

Daemon Status:
  corosync: active/enabled
  pacemaker: active/enabled
  pcsd: active/enabled
```

Everything is running fine. Each node can ping another nodes using 172.16.172.0/24 addresses.

If I reboot a VPS the cluster stays online and virtual IP is moved to another active node. So far everything is fine.

Yesterday due to a DDoS attack an IP address from one of the nodes got black-holed. So the other 3 ones could not connect to it, and since that *corosync* started consume all possible CPU and even more. I had to `killall -9  corosync` to bring the servers back to live.

The cluster started to show all nodes are offline even the local one. Nothing helped, tried:

```
pcs cluster localnode remove node1
```

restarted daemons, stop/start cluster, etc. CPU consumption by *corosync* started to grow each time it started.

I guess I missed something very obvious, and still ma I not too sure what is it exactly.

The cluster has recovered only after the failed node returned back online after 4 hours of a downtime.

Kindly let me know what I need to tune to keep the cluster online even if one-two nodes are not accessible.

Regards,
Alex.

Comment: Corosync is still a pain.